# Dropzone.js submit for multi ids

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

Using Dropzone to submit multi files to multi forms using different ids
but it's only submit for the last id

This is a onclick submit function we used to submit

I got all the rows id selected 
2. Collect it in ids array with the different urls (forms/upload_files/'id')

This is the Dropzone function

```
     if($('#dropzoneDragArea').length > 0){
    submitDropzone = new Dropzone("#id-form",  $.extend({},_dropzone_defaults(),{
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      parallelUploads: 100,
      uploadMultiple: true,
      clickable: '#dropzoneDragArea',
      previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      maxFiles: 2,

   }));
 }
```

This is the onclick function

```
function submit(event) {
var ids = [];

var rows = $('.table-rows').find('tbody tr');
$.each(rows, function() {
    var checkbox = $($(this).find('td').eq(0)).find('input');
    if (checkbox.prop('checked') == true) {

        submitDropzone.options.url = admin_url + 'forms/upload_file/' + checkbox.val();
        ids.push(submitDropzone.options.url);

    }
});

submitDropzone.processQueue();
```

}

Is there any advice please

Comment: what is `submitDropzone.options.url` ? and do you have `autoProcessQueue` set to false?

Comment: This is the main function for Dropzone which contain the files, its working there is no problem with it but only .processQueue() just upload for the last form only

Comment: @AndrewLohr Yes autoProcessQueue is set to false

Comment: You are overriding `options.url` in each iteration, so when you process the queue `options.url` only contains the last url in the array. Now if I understand correctly what you are trying to do is to upload the same file or files to multiple urls with one dropzone?

Comment: @wallek876 Yes that's right and when i put the submitDropzone.processQueue(); in the same iteration it only submit for the first id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the same file or files to multiple urls using the same dropzone, an option is to process the queue, then re-queue the files and update the url in the options and process the queue again for each different url you want to send the files to.

Assuming you already have the `ids` array populated with the urls your submit function could look like:

```
function submit(event) {

  var ids = [];

  // populate urls array

  // submit the files to each url
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    submitDropzone.options.url = myUrls[i];

    submitDropzone.processQueue();

    // if there is still urls requeue the files
    if (i !== myUrls.length - 1) {
      for (let file of submitDropzone.files) {
        if (file.status === Dropzone.SUCCESS || file.status === Dropzone.PROCESSING) {
          file.status = Dropzone.QUEUED;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you have to change the status back to queued because `.processQueue()` doesn't upload files that are already uploaded or processing.